# How to write variable frame rate videos in Python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I have frames in a Python application with the relative time stamps from the start of the video. Is there a way to write a video which has variable frame rate using those timestamps?

I already tried opencv-python and scikit video but it does not seem to be able to write the correct time stamps in case the FPS changes during the video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCV is not a media library. it does not give you this flexibility.

Have a look into [PyAV](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV)

extended [example](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/examples/numpy/generate_video.py) for custom PTS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# extended from https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/examples/numpy/generate_video.py
# added: custom PTS

import numpy as np
import av
from fractions import Fraction

total_frames = 20

container = av.open('test.mp4', mode='w')

stream = container.add_stream('mpeg4', rate=25) # alibi frame rate
stream.width = 480
stream.height = 320
stream.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'

# we'll show frames for 0.5 or 1.0 seconds
# my_pts will say when the next frame is due
# time_base is somewhat arbitrary. this is milliseconds. nice round numbers. I could use 1/2 for my desired PTSes.
stream.codec_context.time_base = Fraction(1, 1000)
my_pts = 0
# ffmpeg time is "complicated". read more at https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/docs/api/time.rst

for frame_i in range(total_frames):

    img = np.empty((480, 320, 3))
    img[:, :, 0] = 0.5 + 0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * (0 / 3 + frame_i / total_frames))
    img[:, :, 1] = 0.5 + 0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * (1 / 3 + frame_i / total_frames))
    img[:, :, 2] = 0.5 + 0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * (2 / 3 + frame_i / total_frames))

    img = np.round(255 * img).astype(np.uint8)
    img = np.clip(img, 0, 255)

    frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img, format='rgb24')

    frame.pts = int(round(my_pts / stream.codec_context.time_base)) # seconds -> counts of time_base

    # calculate time of *next* frame, i.e. how long *this* frame will show
    # show three in quick succession, three slowly, repeat
    my_pts += 0.5 if ((frame_i // 3) % 2 == 0) else 1.0

    for packet in stream.encode(frame):
        container.mux(packet)

# Flush stream
for packet in stream.encode():
    container.mux(packet)

# Close the file
container.close()
```